# How to open a .dem file properly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, text, gdaldem

I have this DEM file downloaded from the internet. It's a text-formatted file and it looks like this:

```
1440   720    30 -9999   450
-9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999
-9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999  -9999
...
```

and so on...

How do I open it in ArcMap to see it visually? Or should I open it with another software?

Comment: Did you try to drag and drop it?

Comment: I have it stored as a .txt file, What extension do I need to set in order to be able to drag and drop ?

Comment: Just try dragging it as it is.

Comment: I can drag and drop, but it's full of Nulls. Nothing visual

Comment: It doesn't have the right header information to be an Esri ASCII DEM http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/com_cpp/GP_ToolRef/Spatial_Analyst_Tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm, or a USGS ASCII DEM https://www.gdal.org/frmt_usgsdem.html. Is there another file that comes with it? It could be one of the formats listed http://www.reliefshading.com/analytical/dem-file-formats/

Comment: The attribute table is full of <Null> value

Comment: it worked with the right header thank you. I will post an answer

Answer (score 4):

Based on Michael Stimson's answer, I've changed the header of the file into

```
ncols        1440
nrows        720
xllcorner    30
yllcorner    450
cellsize     1.000000000000
NODATA_value  -9999
```

It worked like a charm afterwards